# FormGroup doesn't react to validator with costume validator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the whole `fromGroup` to invalid with a custom validator, which doesn't seems to work...

The goal of the code bellow is to compare two instance of a fromGroup.

- If they matched it means no changes has been made so it has to be
  invalid.
- Else it doesn't match it means changes has been made so it has to be
  valid.

My variable `isValid` works correctly when I logged it. It turns to true or false depending on changes.

But I cannot manage to make the from invalid, I've tried many ways form articles and stack-overflow, which has a [stackblitz](https://angular-exmphk.stackblitz.io/) whichi doesn't seems to work neither.

Like `this.updateCyclistForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true});` from [Angular 6 Required only one field from many fields Reactive Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626704/angular-6-required-only-one-field-from-many-fields-reactive-form)

I've seen many similar posts has [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid) which use controls which is not the case here.

```
public updateCyclistForm: FormGroup
public savedStateOfForm: FormGroup

...

constructor(...) {
    ...
    this.savedStateOfForm = new FormGroup({
        status: new FormControl(this.currentReg.status, []),
        role: new FormControl(this.currentReg.role, []),
        passes: new FormControl({ data: this.passesUID }, [])
    })
    this.updateCyclistForm = new FormGroup({
        status: new FormControl(this.currentReg.status, []),
        role: new FormControl(this.currentReg.role, []),
        passes: new FormControl({ data: this.passesUID }, [])
    })
    this.updateCyclistForm.setValidators(this.isValid(this.savedStateOfForm));
}
    
...

isValid = (clone: FormGroup): ValidatorFn => {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
        let isValid = JSON.stringify(clone.value) != JSON.stringify(control.value)
        group.setErrors({ 'valid': isValid });
        this.updateCyclistForm.setErrors({ 'valid': isValid });
        return
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!updateCyclistForm.valid">Save</button>
```

The button is never disabled, why ? What am I doing the wrong way ?

**EDIT :**

I've also tried to use something similar as @Adam's answer. Which make my `button` disabled for life.

```
  isValid = (clone: FormGroup): ValidatorFn => {
        return (group: FormGroup) : ValidationErrors => {
            return {
                invalid: JSON.stringify(clone.value) != JSON.stringify(group.value) ? true : null
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, so your button is disabled, you are very very close. You **MUST** return null from your validator if your control is valid. You cannot return anything else, it is all in the documentation.

Comment: I thought I was returning `null` but it was a null object. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[`setValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) must accept a [`ValidatorFn`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn) function that returns [`ValidationErrors`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors) (or `null`)

```
constructor() {

   // ...

   this.updateCyclistForm.setValidators(this.updateCyclistValidator);
}


...

updateCyclistValidator(ctrl: FormGroup) {
   const valid = // run your validation uisng the values in ctrl

   // if there are no errors, you MUST return null
   if(valid) return null;

   // return your errors, for example:
   return {
     role: 'choose a role'
   }
    
}
```

The presence or absence of errors returned from your validator tells angular if your form is valid or not.

Comment: I've also tried something similar, which did not work. So it make me think that the problem is probably in my `button`.  In your answer how would you use `[disabled]` property ?

Comment: @crg - I'd use disabled exactly as you have used it. Did you use something similar? Or did you use exactly what I posted? Do not use `this` inside the `updateCyclistValidator`. Post what you have tried that is similar.

Comment: I used something similar as your code. Your code does not match what I expect to do. But I tried to get inspired of it.  In my function `isValid` I changed the return value for  `return { invalid: JSON.stringify(clone.value) != JSON.stringify(group.value) ? true : null  }`.

Comment: @crg - You aren't using `setErrors` correctly either. `setErrors({valid:true})` still results in an invalid form. Why your button isn't disabling I don't know. Post your entire component (and template). Maybe this simple example will help you out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d4tqq6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @Adam

This is the solution which came out

```
isValid = (clone: FormGroup) => {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
        return JSON.stringify(clone.value) != JSON.stringify(group.value) ? null : { invalid: JSON.stringify(clone.value) != JSON.stringify(group.value) }
    }
}
```